# How to use @EqualsAndHashCode With Include - Lombok

Tags: java, equals, hashcode, lombok

How to use `@EqualsAndHashCode` With `Include`,  Lombok library for Java.

```
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include( )
```

How to make Equals compare the class id?

Example:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode.Include( )
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User
{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "IDENTITY_USER")
  private Long identity;
}
```

Comment: you mean only compare the `Id`?

Comment: Yes! Only compare the Id.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The `Include` annotation is used on the member(s) you want to include in the `equals` and `hashCode` methods. If you want to specify exactly which members should be used (instead of the default of all non-static non-transient members), you could use the `onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true` option in the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User
{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "IDENTITY_USER")
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private Long identity;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You should use it on the field, it's not something to be used on the class itself. You can check this by checking the definition of the annotation which defines the following targets (field and method, not a class)

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
```

Here is an example of how to use it

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User
{

  @Id
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include()
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "IDENTITY_USER")
  private Long identity;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode), Just add the `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include` or `@EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude` on required fields

> Any class definition may be annotated with @EqualsAndHashCode to let lombok generate implementations of the equals(Object other) and hashCode() methods. By default, it'll use all non-static, non-transient fields, **but you can modify which fields are used (and even specify that the output of various methods is to be used) by marking type members with @EqualsAndHashCode.Include or @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude.** Alternatively, you can specify exactly which fields or methods you wish to be used by marking them with @EqualsAndHashCode.Include and using @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true).

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User
  {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "IDENTITY_USER")
  @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
  private Long identity;
 }
```

Comment: `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include` has effect ONLY with  `@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)` present. (tested on lombok version 1.18.12)